# Exposing KeyCollection to COM?

Tags: vba, com-interop

I'd like to expose my Dictionary(int, obj) to COM so the VBA people can do `for i = 1 to UnitKey.Count`. I thought I could simply `Public Function UnitKeys() As KeyCollection`, but "KeyCollection isn't defined". What is the proper way to expose these?

Comment: Are you writing your code in VBA or something else?

Comment: VBA. Hans gave me some excellent advice on exposing the ValueCollection through a custom interface, but it doesn't seem possible to expose both with the same API (i.e., `.Count` for the keys and values).

Comment: I think you should add more detail to your post. Do you have a class or something else?